# Replicating PCAP packets read by dpdk pktgen for multiple source addresses

Tags: dpdk

I want to use dpdk pktgen to read a pcap file with IP packets. Then replay each IP packet 10 times with unique IP address. Example `if my pcap file has 20 packets, starting with TCP SYN packet, then I want to replay each packet with source IPs in my list, thus total of 10 x 20 packets should be sent`. Basically, I want to resend buffers stored in rte_mbuf again and again, after modifying source IP in each run.

Please let me know what's the best way of doing this.

I first thought of editing the source IP in the rte_mbuf pointed by pkts before calling the rte_eth_tx_burst(info->pid, qid, pkts, cnt) function by having a source IP incrementing loop but it seems that rte_eth_tx_burst function frees up the rte_mbuf pointed by pkts after sending the packet once so I cannot edit the pkts buffer again.

```
static __inline__ void
pktgen_send_burst(port_info_t *info, uint16_t qid)
{
struct mbuf_table   *mtab = &info->q[qid].tx_mbufs;
struct rte_mbuf **pkts, **orig_pkts;
struct qstats_s *qstats;
uint32_t ret, cnt, tap, rnd, tstamp, i, j, orig_cnt;
int32_t seq_idx, num_src_ips=10;

if ((cnt = mtab->len) == 0)
return;

mtab->len = 0;
pkts = mtab->m_table;

if (pktgen_tst_port_flags(info, SEND_RANGE_PKTS))
seq_idx = RANGE_PKT;
else if (pktgen_tst_port_flags(info, SEND_RATE_PACKETS))
seq_idx = RATE_PKT;
else
seq_idx = SINGLE_PKT;

tap = pktgen_tst_port_flags(info, PROCESS_TX_TAP_PKTS);
rnd = pktgen_tst_port_flags(info, SEND_RANDOM_PKTS);
tstamp = pktgen_tst_port_flags(info, (SEND_LATENCY_PKTS | SEND_RATE_PACKETS));

qstats = &info->qstats[qid];
qstats->txpkts += cnt;
for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
qstats->txbytes += rte_pktmbuf_data_len(pkts[i]);
rte_mbuf_refcnt_update(pkts[i], num_src_ips) /*Updating refcnt to num_src_ips*/
}


/* Send all of the packets before we can exit this function */
while (cnt) {

if (rnd)
pktgen_rnd_bits_apply(info, pkts, cnt, NULL);

if (tstamp)
pktgen_tstamp_apply(info, pkts, cnt, seq_idx);

ret = rte_eth_tx_burst(info->pid, qid, pkts, cnt);

if (tap)
pktgen_do_tx_tap(info, pkts, ret);

pkts += ret;
cnt -= ret;
}
}
```

Comment: is your question `what should I add into source code of pkt-gen allow me to send customized packet (IP address) multiple times?` or `how can I retain the mbuf in memory for n times?`. can you please re-edit for the right question as it is not clear. Answer to the latter `for any dpdk application one can make use of mbuf field refcnt to alter the behaviour. One can use DPDK API rte_mbuf_refcnt_update for the same.`

Comment: I am trying to replay a pcap file using multiple source IPs from a list(say 10 IPs), for example if my pcap file has 20 packets, starting with TCP SYN packet, then I want to replay each packet with source IPs in my list, thus total of 10 x 20 packets should be sent. For which I tried to create a loop on top of while (cnt) loop in code snippet, but it only worked for first IP, for rest of the IPs it didn't worked as the memory to which pkts was pointing didn't have the actual buffer once its transmitted by rte_eth_tx_burst, thus I want that memory pointed by pkts to remain valid while looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to retain the DPDK packet buffer in the memory please use `rte_mbuf_refcnt_update` to update `mbuf ptr -> refcnt` from `1` to `10`. This retains the buffer in memory till either `rte_eth_tx_burst` or `rte_pktmbuf_free`or `combination of both` is invoked 10 times for same mbuf.

note: please add code to the current snippet to

- Ensure the current MBUF is IP.
- re-calculate the IP checksum when IP header is modified.

[EDIT-1] based on skype conversation, highlighted the main area to focus. Changes on actual dpdk-pktgen will affect function and performance. Recommended using dpdk-burstreplay or custom built DPDK app.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding current code snippet, I have taken 2 new variables orig_cnt to save the burst size and orig_pkts to save the location of starting pointer, and then add a for loop to modify source IPs before the while (cnt) loop is called.

Comment: Hi Ravi, I do not see any attempt to update mbuf refcnt. Is there something you are asking as part of the above comment?

Comment: Sorry Vipin, I thought you want to see my original code so I pasted it without refcnt update, now I have updated it where I am setting refcnt count with num_src_ips

Comment: ok, hope it working for you as you requested. If you find the solution useful please accept   the answer. Thanks

Comment: It still didn't work, I noticed the same behavior happening earlier. I am applying GDB, would let you know what exactly is going wring now.

Comment: can you come over skype or zoom as it is easy to debug with your environment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221446/discussion-between-ravi-and-vipin-varghese).

Comment: Hi Vipin, using refcnt doesn't really helped. It only worked for few cycles till buffers from the memory pool are not reused, after that I am seeing duplicate packets, please let me know if there is a way to avoid duplicate packets.

Comment: Hi Ravi, you have to share more details about the problem (recommending a chat). Please note as discussed best option for your use case having custom application rather than hacking in pktgen logic